# PSCP wildcard to fixed name

Tags: linux, pscp

I'm trying to copy a file from Windows to Linux, but I don't know the exact filename (it's a war file from a maven project, so I don't know the current version.
My example:

```
pscp -pw <password> "F:\Maven\jenkins\workspace\<project-name>\target\<project-name>-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war"  user@192.168.1.132:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT.war
```

this fails with this error:

```
pscp: remote filespec /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT.war: not a directory
```

Is there any way to use wildcards, that pscp won't use as a directory?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command which worked for me. This is just a **syntax** and you need to modify the **source** and **destination file path**.

```
pscp.exe -pw passwd -l uname -sftp " source-directory-file-path " x.x.x.x:remote-directory-file-path
```

Comment: Hi @manjesh23. It didn't work, I'm getting the same error "not a directory".

Comment: Can you please help me with full command you are using?

Comment: My example is the real one.

Comment: pscp -pw <password> "F:\Maven\jenkins\workspace\aaa\target\aaa-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war"  my-user@192.168.1.132:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT.war

Comment: Try this: pscp.exe -pw passwd -l uname -sftp "F:\Maven\jenkins\workspace\aaa\target\aaa-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.wa‌​r" 192.168.1.132:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT.war

Comment: Yes, this works fine, but what I'm looking for is to be able to use a wildcar in the source file. 
`pscp.exe -pw passwd -l uname -sftp "F:\Maven\jenkins\workspace\aaa\target\aaa-*.wa‌​‌​r" 192.168.1.132:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT.war`

Comment: Wildcard will not work because you are specifying source wildcard but destination is a file name. Its just like over-writing the destination file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46928/discussion-between-manjesh23-and-german).